# EJB lookup throws error: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: vmcid: SUN minor code: 257 completed: Maybe

Tags: ejb, corba

When my application  does EJB lookup using remote interface, I get following exception. It was working fine and in recently build something has changed which broke it.

```
java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079745 Maybe; nested exception is:
        org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:279)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:205)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(BCELStubBase.java:225)
```

Comment: If you want, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473939/ejb-lookup-failing-with-namingexception/1496306#1496306

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely this is a version discrepancy between the client and the server. For example, you recompiled the client code and the shared classes for the client, but they differ from the same classes on the server.

Comment: Exactly. This was the problem. We got friendly which was latest version. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](http://markmail.org/message/l5jooxifxlt6a7v4), MARSHAL/SUN/257 means "could not find class". Apparently, this happens when it reads a value type from a CORBA message and can't find an implementation class.

Comment: Yes, it was different version of class.