# Help in EJB Creating Stateless Session Bean

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I am beginner to EJB concept.
I just read creating stateless session bean !!
Here we create 2 interface and a bean.

In that Home Interface we use a method create for creating instances.

But is that create() method a keyword. It is not showing anything in eclipse.

It will good if some can post how to create simple hello world stateless session bean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Senthilnathan You can see a good Tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473939/ejb-lookup-failing-with-namingexception/1496306#1496306

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://openejb.apache.org/ejb3-tutorial.html) has examples on both stateless and stateful beans. Take a look. It is from OpenEJB but this shouldn't bother you - all EJB implementations conform to the EJB specification.

Comment: That tutorial is quite dated (1999) and does not cover EJB3.

Comment: @Matthieu Cormier thanks. I updated my answer with a fresher one

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for. Your question is tagged EJB 3 but you are mentioning EJB 2 concepts. So, unless you explicitly want to learn EJB 2 to understand how things were done in old times, I suggest to look at EJB 3 resources, e.g. the [Chapter 22, Session Bean Examples](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnboc.html) of the Java EE 5 tutorial.