# java.net.SocketTimeoutException while lookup in EJB

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, ejb

In my application I got the following error when i trying to lookup some EJB object from tomcat.

```
2012-01-09 15:54:00,825 ERROR [ AccessRight ] NAMING EXCEPTION IN FACTORYjavax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]
2012-01-09 15:54:00,825 ERROR BaseLoadServlet.java getMenuCollection(): Exception : com.elitecore.billing.delegates.base.exception.LookupException
```

Can anybody tell what is this error ?

Comment: This might be a duplicate or similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473939/ejb-lookup-failing-with-namingexception

Comment: Can you post the JBoss version and the lookup code?